# Filter box on review is displayed under the markdown bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, filtering

This is not a big problem, but the filter box is under the markdown bar when you want to see the box during a review (with the editor):

[image]

A simple `z-index: 1` on the `<div>` solve the problem:

```
<div class="review-filter-popup" style="top: -26px; left: 219px; display: block; z-index: 1;">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We added the `z-index` to fix the problem. Thanks for the report.